# How to display randomly selected images inside a div?

Tags: php, scandir

I'm trying to display two randomly selected images from a dir

Instead of images, img.names are displayed

```
$dir    = 'memb_area/captcha/imgs/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$rand_keys = array_rand($files, 2);
echo $files[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $files[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

Also tried:

```
echo '<img src="memb_area/captcha/imgs">' + 'echo $files[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";'
```

And - is it possible to print these pictures inside a separate div on a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is not a valid PHP concatenation character. `.` is. By using `+`, you are effectively **adding** these two strings, which when converted to integers, equate to `0`.

This line:
`echo '<img src="memb_area/captcha/imgs">' + 'echo $files[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";'`

should be:(updated)
`echo "<img src=\"memb_area/captcha/imgs/".$files[$rand_keys[0]]."\">".PHP_EOL;`

**Update 01:** (OP's Comment: *but after refreshing, after two or three times - nothing is displayed. Next refresh - image is displayed... and so on.*)

Scandir [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) (Example #1) says that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)
```

So, maybe your `scandir($foo)` is returning an array with two keys having *invisible* directories as their values.

Try this code and let me know:

```
$dir    = 'memb_area/captcha/imgs/';
$files = scandir($dir);

if($files[0] == ".") unset($files[0]);
if($files[1] == "..") unset($files[1]);

$files = array_values($files); // reset array keys back to 0,1,2..

$rand_keys = array_rand($files, 2);
echo $files[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $files[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";  

echo "<img src=\"memb_area/captcha/imgs/".$files[$rand_keys[0]]."\">".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: `Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in ...`

Comment: Try the updated code. I have fixed the single & Double quotes mis-matching.

Comment: @ Dawinder, your code now partially works. Image is displayed, but after refreshing  - each second time - nothing is displayed.

Comment: @Alergo its `v`, not `w` in `Davinder` :) Ok, see Update 01 for the possible cause & solution for this.

Comment: @ Davinder, excuse me for "w". Image is now diplayed, but after refreshing, after two or three times - nothing is displayed. Next refresh - image is displayed... and so on. This is what I have `echo "<img src=\"memb_area/captcha/imgs/".$files[$rand_keys[0]]."\">".PHP_EOL;`

Comment: No problem, sorry I commented first and Updated my answer later. See **Update 01**, try it and let me know.

Comment: the thing that sometimes the image is displayed and sometimes not is a symptom that `.` & `..` values are present in `$files`

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be error in path.
try this: 
`echo '<img src="memb_area/captcha/imgs/">' + 'echo $files[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";'`

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct path. Check if path is valid using Browser

Comment: I think, without correct path img.names should not be displayed

Comment: i know u r getting proper names, but while displaying u need to prefix the Directory path properly.